# CSV import via COPY FROM won't work with NULL values contained

Tags: database, file, postgresql, csv, import

I've a CSV file and want to import this via the Postgres command "COPY x FROM y" in my  database. This database has two columns: a column called "id" (serial, NULL not allowed) and a "value" column (varchar, NULL is allowed and a constraint is applied). I'll provide the short create script for the test database below.
The CSV is obtained by exporting it from an OpenOffice spreadsheet. The CSV content is also provided at the end.

**My problem:**

When executing the following command ...

```
COPY mytable FROM '/tmp/testdata.csv' CSV HEADER NULL AS E'\N';
```

... I'm getting this error message:

```
ERROR:  value for domain car_manufacturer violates check constraint "car_manufacturer_format"
CONTEXT:  COPY mytable, line 3, column value: "\N"

********** Error **********

ERROR: value for domain car_manufacturer violates check constraint "car_manufacturer_format"
SQL state: 23514
Context: COPY mytable, line 3, column value: "\N"
```

Here is the content of the **CSV** file (exported directly from OpenOffice, so it should conform to the standards):

```
"ID","value"
1,"Mercedes"
2,"\N"
```

Obviously, Postgres has some problems in understanding that the "\N" in my CSV file is meant to be a NULL value (which is actually allowed in this column). First, it is checking the whole string "\N" against the constraint. As it does not conform to the RegexPattern defined in the constraint, it will provide the error mentioned above. I tried several modifications of my COPY-FROM-Command but none of these led to a successful import.

**In short:** I need a solution for allowing Postgres me to import a csv via the copy-from-command and, moreover, being allowed to have "\N"-entries in string/varchar columns representing NULL-values.

I really need to do it with the Copy command because I want to automate the import process by using a script. When using phpPGAdmin for importing the CSV everything works fine. This is due to the fact, that phpPgAdmin is sending INSERT-Commands to the postgres server. So it is obviously not using the "copy from"-command...

**Additional info:**

Here is the **create script** for the database:

```
CREATE DOMAIN car_manufacturer AS VARCHAR (100) CONSTRAINT car_manufacturer_format CHECK
(VALUE SIMILAR TO '[A-Z][A-Za-z]+|');
COMMENT ON DOMAIN car_manufacturer IS 'The name of a car manufacturer (e.g, Ford, BMW, Chrysler, Mercedes etc.)';

CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  "ID" serial NOT NULL,
  "value" car_manufacturer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_mytable PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mytable OWNER TO postgres;
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers,
Philipp

PS: My example is boiled down in order to show you the actual problem. So, please, don't be bothered by the triviality of this example :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually don't use quoting for character fields and have a different delimiter to avoid difficulty with embedded commas, e.g. '|' when exporting open office to csv. 
Then on import specify the delimiter and also escape the backslash to specify null E'\\N'.

Comment: Hi Gavin, using E'\\N' instead of E'\N' doesn't help. The same exact error message will come. Furthermore, quoting character fields is a common standard and is also used by OpenOffice and other CSV-Exporters. The separator is a comma by default. My CSV is sticking to this standard and thus should be importable without any problems. "\N" is also a valid Null-Value string in the Postgres-Specs and has to be used in this case, because I'm simply not allowed to change it.

Comment: The copy is interpreting the "\N" as a string value which is why I suggested the above approach but if you can't use that then I suppose you could put a before insert trigger on the table to convert the "\N" value to a null !

Comment: I agree that the copy command is probably misinterpreting the "\N" as a string. However, creating a before insert trigger is rather a work-around than a solution. Look, I would have to create a trigger on each table of the database, at least, for all tables I'm planning a regular CSV import. This solution would lack a lot of flexibility. I'm sure that there must be a way of getting the single-line command working (if it's not a bug) ...

Comment: Me again. I think the best solution would be - as Gavin suggested in his initial response - to export the data from OpenOffice by not using double-quotes and to choose a unique delimiter symbol (such as |). Although, this is not a standard csv-format as such, it would provide the quickest and most efficent solution to my problem. regards

Answer (score 0):

"\N" is a value that can be interpreted as a "New line" command.

Try to use another character, like "@".